# Drone CI multiple triggers

Tags: continuous-integration, drone.io

I have successfully set up a pull request trigger for our Drone CI but as soon as I added the cron trigger the pull requests trigger stops working.
The working configuration is as bellow:

```yaml
trigger:
  event:
    - pull_request
```

The edited trigger is:

```yaml
trigger:
  event:
    - pull_request
    - cron
  cron:
    - nightly
```

Any idea why it is causing this? Maybe the configuration is wrong but I could not find anything else beside this in the docs.